# Change default H2db to MySql for jbpm integration with springboot

Tags: mysql, eclipse, spring-boot, jbpm

To integrate it with MySql I have already tried the following links

https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v3/userguide/thejbpmdatabase.html

https://manthapavankumar.wordpress.com/2013/08/04/configure-jbpm-with-mysql/

http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-jbpm/jbpm6/configuring-jbpm-6-to-use-a-non-default-database

But still I am not getting my data being stored in MySql.

We have used STS and MySQL workbench for development purpose.

Please help me out with this

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the skeleton generated from https://start.jbpm.org/?

If you do, you could lately use the sample application-mysql.properties provided on business-application-service/src/main/resources and config your database settings.

You should than remember to activate the correct profile when running launch.sh, adding the parameters `-P mysql` to the sample usage command.

Comment: Do you know how to make it work with SQL Sever? Do you have any sample?

Comment: The samples from [start.jbpm.org](https://start.jbpm.org) have different profiles and configuration samples for some databases, none is MS SQL Server. You would have to make your own configuration and include your driver. [This](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/SetUpJBPM53ToUseMSSQLServer2008) might lead you on the right direction.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This link is quite old, and it is for JBOSS. Now I am having hard time to make Spring Boot + JBPM 7 + SQL Server work